# SQL date range calculation

Tags: sql

I have two tables one contain dates (startdate and EndDate) and rate and the other transaction table have dates and amount. I want get transactions between startdate and enddate in the transactions table and divide them rates for that period. I just want to use item code 1 only. e.g

table rate

```
startdate   enddate      rate     item
2011-01-01  2011-01-03   40.00    1
2011-01-07  2011-01-10   10.00    1
2011-01-07  2011-01-10   10.00    2
```

Table Transaction

```
date            Amount
2011-01-01      500.00
2011-01-02      160.00
2011-01-02      140.00
2011-01-03      600.00
2011-01-07      920.00
2011-01-10      1600.00
```

Results

```
date            Amount
2011-01-01      500.00/40 
2011-01-02      160.00/40
2011-01-02      140.00/40
2011-01-03      600.00/40
2011-01-07      920.00/10
2011-01-10      1600.00/10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.date, t.Amount / r.Rate AS Amount
FROM Transaction t
INNER JOIN rate r ON t.date>=r.startdate and t.date <=r.enddate
```

You could use BETWEEN, but, in some DBMS, if I'm not wrong, it's exclusive...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple join.  Since you are using dates (without times) and have the end date in the rates table, the following should work:

```
select t.date, t.amount / r.rate
from transaction t left outer join
     rates r
     on t.date between r.startdate and r.enddate
```